# Debugging C# Console Application in VSCode using DNU/DNX and project.json

Tags: c#, macos, mono, visual-studio-code, dnx

Problem (this is all on OSX btw.):

1. Make a new C# Console Application through `yo aspnet`, `dnu restore`, `dnu build`, `dnx run` <- all is peachy
2. Add dependency (e.g. Newtonsoft.JSON, Akka) to project, `dnu restore`, `dnu build`, `dnx run` <- all is peachy
3. Look up this site to see how it's supposed to work. https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_mono-debugging (oh and piece together the rest by googling and through trial and error)
4. Add `using Newtonsoft.JSON` in Program.cs and... actually use it.
5. Try compiling/debugging
6. meh...

Lets investigate:

`mcs -debug Program.cs` cannot compile Program.cs because it can't find the dependency installed by `dnu restore` which resides somewhere in `~/.dnx/packages/...`. Makes kinda sense. So using `mcs` to compile is not the way to go?

Others say "use `xbuild` or whatever". But i don't wanna make `.csproj` files. I wanna use `project.json` and DNU/DNX. (and i haven't tried actually)

So what can you do? Try fiddle around with `tasks.json` to make `dnu build` work.

Here's what i got.

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dnu",
    "options": {
        "cwd": "/Users/meh/Development/code/HelloWorld"
    },
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

It isn't pretty, but it actually gets the work done.

Now the part that i can't get to work is the debugging part.

So `dnu build` create the output in some directory like this `/Users/meh/Development/code/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/dnx451/HelloWorld.dll`

If you try to make it work like in this `launch.json`, which works for the simple `Program.cs` file generated without dependencies, you get nothing.
I tried it through the console to see why it wasn't working. So why? Because `mono` can't find the necessary dependencies. Why? Because they're not in said directory.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "mono",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/Users/meh/Development/code/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/dnx451/HelloWorld.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": ".",
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "mono",
            "request": "attach",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

If you use `dnx run` or whatever you have configured to run the compiled program it works of course.

So looking around `dnx --help` i've seen a nice `dnx --debug` option. If you run that on console you get this nice output:

```
Blah:HelloWorld meh$ dnx --debug run
Process Id: 19228
Waiting for the debugger to attach...
```

Thing is... i have no clue what port the debugger is waiting on. And it actually seems that `mono-sgen` (which `ps` tells me the PID belongs to) isn't actually listening on any port. I tried to check via `lsof`.

My fear is that `dnx --debug` is actually not really working as i've seen random comments on github issues here and there mentioning something.

That's it. That's how far i got.

So. Has anyone gotten any further? Has anyone even tried? Am i an idiot for trying to make console applications through DNX/DNU and use VSCode to program and debug it? Am i just doing something completely wrong?

Any takers?

**Edit 1**: 
You have to add this to `project.json` to get an entry point in the compiled DLL file for mono to be able to run the program.

```
"compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
},
```

**Edit 2**: 
Other things i tried...

**1.** Look at what `dnx run` actually does.

And what does it do?

```
45588 s000  U+     0:02.11 mono /Users/meh/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin/Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Mono.dll run
```

It calls something called `Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Mono.dll` from inside your project directory that gets used to call all the stuff.

Sadly there's no real way to put that command into a `launch.json` entry to make it a) start off in the right directory and b) omit the .DLL file name from the command.

This is the best i could wrangle out of `launch.json`.

```
cd '/Users/meh/Development/code/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/dnx451';  'mono' '--debug' '--debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=127.0.0.1:61396' '/Users/meh/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin/Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Mono.dll' 'HelloWorld.dll' 'run'
```

As is evident, it's the wrong directory for the `Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Mono.dll` to run from and you can't make it omit the `HelloWorld.dll` parameter.

The other thing is. Even if you could make VSCode generate the right command line it doesn't work. Opening up a terminal and executing a command like this gets you into debugging mode:

```
cd '/Users/meh/Development/code/HelloWorld/';  'mono' '--debug' '--debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=127.0.0.1:61396' '/Users/meh/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin/Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Mono.dll' 'run'
```

And then attaching to the debugger from VSCode via the attach config in `launch.json`, as seen above (of course the port needs to match), runs the program but the debugger can't get a hook in. Guess that's because you're not really debugging `HelloWorld.dll`. Or `dnx build` doesn't output debugging symbols. Probably the last one.

**2.** Tell mono where to fine the dependencies.

So i dug around the `man mono` and found out that you can tell mono via `$MONO_PATH` where to look for libraries.

But making a script and slapping all the paths found in `~/.dnx/packages` is no good, because in there contained are all the libraries you ever have `dnu restored`. Every version of them.

So how to only get the libraries your `project.json` references? Well i dug around `dnu` for a bit and found `dnu publish`. Which generates an `output` directory inside of `bin` that contains a number of things. One of those is a folder called `packages` containing all your project dependencies.

Yeay? No!

Because what `dnu publish` doesn't do is create a compiled .DLL file. Instead it creates a shell script that seems to on the fly compile your stuff. But whatever. We just wanted the DLLs anyways.

So what do we have. We have a `dnu build` to get us a nice .DLL file. And we have a `dnu publish` that collects the dependencies for us.

Now you can use a little shell magic to collect the paths for us in a `$MONO_PATH` friendly way.

```
ls -d $PWD/bin/output/approot/packages/*/*/lib/net45 | tr '\n' ':'
```

The problem again lies with `launch.json`. It has a nice property called `env : {}` but VSCode, when generating the actual command to launch the debugger, puts all the stuff you put in there in single quotes. Which gets interpreted as literal strings. So you can't actually put something like the little command above into it. **sad trombone**

Btw. if you open a terminal again, and export the output of the above mentioned script into `$MONO_PATH` and then run the `mono` command by hand like in the other try you can then again try to attach the VSCode debugger to it, the command runs but the debugger can't hook into it. Again i think it's either no debugger symbols or well the other thing.

```
 Flash:HelloWorld meh$ export MONO_PATH=$(ls -d $PWD/bin/output/approot/packages/*/*/lib/net45 | tr '\n' ':')
 Flash:HelloWorld meh$ echo $MONO_PATH 
 /Users/meh/Development/code/HelloWorld/bin/output/approot/packages/Akka/1.0.5/lib/net45:/Users/meh/Development/code/HelloWorld/bin/output/approot/packages/Microsoft.CSharp/4.0.1-beta-23516/lib/net45:/Users/meh/Development/code/HelloWorld/bin/output/approot/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/8.0.1-beta3/lib/net45:/Users/meh/Development/code/HelloWorld/bin/output/approot/packages/System.Collections/4.0.11-beta-23516/lib/net45:/Users/meh/Development/code/HelloWorld/bin/output/approot/packages/System.Linq/4.0.1-beta-23516/lib/net45:/Users/meh/Development/code/HelloWorld/bin/output/approot/packages/System.Threading/4.0.11-beta-23516/lib/net45:
 Flash:HelloWorld meh$ cd '/Users/meh/Development/code/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/dnx451';  'mono' '--debug' '--debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=127.0.0.1:61396' 'HelloWorld.dll'
 Meh
 Hello World
 {
   "blah": "blub"
 }
 From ConsoleActor: blah blub
 From ConsoleActor: blubberblub

 Flash:dnx451 meh$
```

Conclusion for now. I'm all out of ideas. And short of using gulp or other build tools, like @richardsonmarkj suggested, i don't see it happening any time soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNX is deprecated, so this question is moot now.

Leaving this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/10/experimental-net-core-debugging-in-vs-code/) here that shows experimental .net core debugging with vscode.

Answer (score 0):

I've also been trying to understand this scenario. I walked through your steps and I end up at a different place. I do not see a dependency issue. When I attempt to debug from VSCode I get this in my terminal window-

```
cd '/Users/markr/Projects/ConsoleApplication/bin/Debug/dnxcore50';  'mono' '--debug' '--debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=127.0.0.1:58907' 'ConsoleApplication.dll'
Assembly '/Users/markr/Projects/ConsoleApplication/bin/Debug/dnxcore50/ConsoleApplication.dll' doesn't have an entry point.
```

The difference may be that after adding Newtonsoft.JSON to my dependencies -

```
 "dependencies": {
  "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.2"
},
```

in my project.json file I did do a `dnu restore`

**EDIT:**  adding `"compilationOptions": { "emitEntryPoint": true },` to my project.json file did fix my entrypoint issue.

Here's my code: -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        JArray array = new JArray();
        array.Add("Manual text");
        array.Add(new DateTime(2000, 5, 23));

        JObject o = new JObject();
        o["MyArray"] = array;

        string json = o.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(json);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

I think the debugger is having the same issue as you saw with `mcs -debug`. Running that app from the command line via `mono ConsoleApplication.dll` give this

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
```

Copying the Newtonsoft.Json.dll file into the directory fixes the issue and the app will run. Also at that point the debugger seems to work as I mentioned in the comments below.

I think we need a build step to collect the dependencies and place them in the output directory.

**EDIT:** I have verified this. I pulled Newtonsoft.Json.dll into the root and changed the tasks.json to  -

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "mcs",
    "options": {
        "cwd": "/Users/markr/Projects/ConsoleApplication"
    },
    "args": [
        "*.cs",
        "-debug",
        "-r:Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
    ],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Debugging works as expected when pointed to the new Program.exe. This is effectively removing dnu/dnx which will mean project management will become tedious. So you need to instead find a method for collecting the non-framework dependencies into the output/runtime cwd so that the Mono vm can find them. Seems like something Nant or Gulp might be useful for.

Comment: that's easy. you have to add     "compilationOptions": { "emitEntryPoint": true }, into project.json

Comment: oh and can you share your launch.json?

Comment: Okay the debugger starts now but VSCode doesn't seem to be in control as a breakpoint on the first line of Main() does not get hit. I am able to pause the program in the ReadKey() method though and inspect the stack. So now it might be a symbols problem.

Comment: did you actually start using something from Newtonsoft.Json? create a new JObject in your Program.cs?

Comment: my launch.json is the same is yours except for the path.  Also debugging dnx451 works better than debugging dnxcore50.

Comment: "Seems like something Nant or Gulp might be useful for" <- that would defeat the purpose of using dnx/dnu in the first place. can just make a csproj file and use xbuild then. it is annoying. i'll add some edits of other stuff i tried and failed with.

Comment: but yeah. i fully expected that if you manually copy the needed dependencies into the output directory that it would work. but in the end it boils down to the microsoft dnx/dnu guys having to add debugging support in their stuff and make the build/debug work with their runtime foo.